# Moving certain containers to sides without harming other containers

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been looking around and could not find a way to move specific containers to the sides of the page, whilst leaving the other containers intact.

What I would would like to achieve is the following layouts for mobile and desktop screens, respectively: [*Desktop*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVnqR.jpg) and [*Mobile*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1fj7.jpg)

Note the colors: the **third** row on the mobile layout should become a **left** column on the desktop layout, and the **fifth** row on the mobile layout should become a **right** column on the desktop layout.
The rest of the rows should stay as a middle column on desktops.

I was trying to achieve that by using Flexbox but could not get it to done properly.

I would love to hear suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed like an interesting exercise. It's a bit rough but the basics are there.

[**Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YwGvWx)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child,
.aside {
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
  order: 1;
}
.aside {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .child {
    order: 2;
    width: 80%;
    flex: 1 0 25%;
  }
  .left {
    order: 1;
    width: 10%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .right {
    order: 3;
    width: 10%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child">One</div>
  <div class="child">Two</div>
  <div class="aside left">Three</div>
  <div class="child">Four</div>
  <div class="aside right">Five</div>
  <div class="child">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting to see how `flex-wrap: wrap` works on columns. Thank you!